# Validating beans on service method during tests with Spring MockMvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, mockmvc

I have a Spring 5 web application which does validations only on service level DTOs. That is to say, the incoming request is not validated in controller, but the DTO going into a service layer method is validated on that level. This is a requirement because this is how this is done on other applications and other people want to keep it like that for consistency.

I have tests that use Spring MockMvc to test the controller methods. I'd like to test the error response on validation errors but when I run my tests, bean validation is not done. It works fine when I build and deploy the app, though. Validation also works for tests if I put the validation annotations on the class representing the incoming request and add @Valid to the controller method argument corresponding to the request. It just doesn't work when its done on the service layer.

**So my question is is this even supposed to work with MockMvc, that is to say, should validation occur normally when the controller calls the service method?** Or is there some configuration I need to have in place for this to work during tests? I doubt it since validation works if I try adding it to controller level...

Here is my test class setup:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {MyTestConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

private MockMvc mvc;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

@Before
public void setup() throws Exception {
    this.mvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
}
```

The MyTestConfig class just has @EnableWebMvc annotation, base packages for scanning and some unrelated bean definitions.

My DTO has @NotNull annotation on a property, the service method has a @Validated annotation on the class and a @Valid annotation on the method parameter which is the DTO.

With these settings, when I make a request in a test to the controller endpoint using the MockMvc instance mvc above, validation does not occur on the service method.

So is this even supposed to work?

Comment: Validation at the controller level and validation at the service level are different beasts. The first is backed into Spring MVC (it is triggered in the `HandlerAdapter`) whereas for the validation on the service level AOP is required. You probably haven't setup the latter and hence it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Yeah some AOP related issue is what I also suspected.

Comment: It would have to be some test configuration issue though, since validation works when I build and deploy...

Comment: But why a special test config? You are then just testing your test config. You should be loading your actual config and override the specific beans for test (like your datasource).